# How do you create a temporary table to SELECT from off an array? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to do a query like this...

```
INSERT INTO article_keyword (article_id, keyword_id, strength)

SELECT ?, keyword.keyword_id, strength_table.strength FROM keyword

INNER JOIN (SELECT 5 AS strength, 'keyword1' AS keyword) AS strength_table
    ON strength_table.keyword=keyword.keyword

WHERE keyword IN ('keyword1', 'keyword2', 'keyword3');
```

At the `INNER JOIN` above... I need to `SELECT` from an array in PHP that looks like... `$array = ['keyword1' => 9, 'keyword2' => 11, 'keyword4' => 13];` where the value is the strength and the key is the keyword. Essentially... I want to `INNER JOIN` a temporary/dynamic table with the fields `keyword` and `strength` based on that array. I don't need help with the PHP/PDO, but how would I put a table there? Is there an easy way to generate a table I can `SELECT` from?

The executed SQL works... it inserts a row into article_keyword: `('some article id', 5, 'keyword1 id')`.

TL;DR: can I change `(SELECT 5 AS strength, 'keyword1' AS keyword)` into a table based off an array?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `UNION ALL` to build an inline table in a subquery:

```
INSERT INTO article_keyword (article_id, keyword_id, strength)
    SELECT ?, keyword.keyword_id, strength_table.strength
    FROM keyword
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT  9 AS strength, 'keyword1' AS keyword
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 11 AS strength, 'keyword2' AS keyword
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 13 AS strength, 'keyword4' AS keyword
    ) AS strength_table
        ON strength_table.keyword=keyword.keyword
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7r2ENgZdgBcgMSfuiB9rrG/0)

Another way is to insert your values into a temporary table. Then use that table in your INSERT statement:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE tmp_strength_table (strength INT, keyword VARCHAR(50));
INSERT INTO tmp_strength_table (strength, keyword) VALUES
    ( 9, 'keyword1'),
    (11, 'keyword2'),
    (13, 'keyword4');

INSERT INTO article_keyword (article_id, keyword_id, strength)
    SELECT ?, keyword.keyword_id, strength_table.strength
    FROM keyword
    INNER JOIN tmp_strength_table AS strength_table
        ON strength_table.keyword=keyword.keyword
```

[db-fidle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/36bP1gWpcthHSt8NaS3jqT/0)

There is also a way without creating a table. You can just use subqueries in the VALUES clause:

```
INSERT INTO article_keyword (article_id, strength, keyword_id) VALUES
  (?, 9,  (SELECT keyword_id FROM keyword WHERE keyword = 'keyword1')),
  (?, 11, (SELECT keyword_id FROM keyword WHERE keyword = 'keyword2')),
  (?, 13, (SELECT keyword_id FROM keyword WHERE keyword = 'keyword4'))
```

[db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/n8gDdE1Bx5tcCcHciqpUKt/0)

Note: In this case you will need to repeat the `article_id` (bind multiple times).

#### MariaDB 10.3 and *Table Value Constructors*

[Table Value Constructors](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/table-value-constructors/) were implemented in MariaDB 10.3.3. We can now use `VALUES` syntax to create inline tables:

```
INSERT INTO article_keyword (article_id, keyword_id, strength)
  WITH strength_table(strength, keyword) AS (
    VALUES (9, 'keyword1'), (11, 'keyword2'), (13, 'keyword4')
  )
  SELECT ?, keyword.keyword_id, strength_table.strength
  FROM keyword
  INNER JOIN strength_table AS strength_table
    ON strength_table.keyword=keyword.keyword
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=01db1933b3eab5deb9d0b06addcc9df6)

Comment: Wow, what a fantastic answer. That's exactly what I was looking for. If I could ask you one more thing... is the second method more efficient? It seems like it would be if you're handling a lot of data, right? I'm in the process of testing it, but if you know off the top of your head that would save me some time.

Comment: Without tests I can't say what is faster. The first method has an overhead of a "huge" `UNION` query. On the other hand it's a single statement, while you need to execute three statements for the second method. Every statement adds an overhead. I guess at some amount of data the second way will be faster. But be aware of the risks when using temporary tables for DML. If you use replication you should read [this](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/replication-features-temptables.html).

Comment: @JohnCullen I would also test prepared statements in a single transaction. The performance penalty might be not that high, but the code wil be much simpler.